# web page is hanging while loading from DB and large data not showing on charts in asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am working on asp.net mvc 5 
I am displaying charts using dot net highcharts
while on displaying data on charts, after display the page hangs for a while and then it becomes responsive 
I don't know what is going wrong 
I am using VS 2015 and SQL SERVER 2014

Also the data on the chart is not showing when the data become large 
for this I have used `turboThreshold: 1100` here the data less than 1100 pint is shown but still page hangs for a while after that it become responsive but when the data is above 1100 point it will not show any data,
 when i make the value of `turboThreshold: greater than 2000` it displays all data but it hangs the page and then it displays an error to wait or kill the page

I am using Google Chrome to view the application

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an official module for Highcharts to increase the performance while working with large datasets.

It is called [boost.js](http://www.highcharts.com/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost).

Majority of charting solutions are using **SVG** technology and in all SVG based charting solutions, performance decreases after adding a couple thousand of SVG elements to **DOM**.

Highcharts developers solves this problem with this [boost.js](http://www.highcharts.com/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) module.

It is using **HTML5 Canvas** technology insted of SVG. Charts are rendering with HTML5 Canvas and you can still access to DOM like SVG based solutions without any difference. All you have to do is to include this module in your project and your charts will load faster.

Comment: You are a time saver Emre. just one question more. i am using multiple graphs (line and bar)  so this boost.js file will support all type of the graphs i.e. i just have to include this file and all the way it supports my all graphs or i have to do some changes in it?

Comment: Exactly. This module supports all chart types (Line, bar, area scatter, pie etc.). There is a demo with 1.000.000 points on chart [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/canvas-scatter/) which is rendering really fast.